# I am trying to shift these buttons to right but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I am trying to tag along with a tutorial that am seeing on YouTube for him it's working fine but it doesn't seem to be working on my end. Kindly suggest the solution.

```css
.controls {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 50%;
  right: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4tMg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="controls"></div>
<div class="control control-1 active-btn">
  <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
</div>
<div class="control control-2" data-id="about">
  <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
</div>
<div class="control control-3" data-id="portfolio">
  <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
</div>
<div class="control control-4" data-id="blogs">
  <i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i>
</div>
<div class="control control-5" data-id="contact">
  <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: We are not watching the same video at the same time, so we're going to need a lot more context from you...

Comment: can u please tell me what do i need to provide

Comment: Please read [ask] for what is expected of questions. The section titled "Help others reproduce the problem" would seem to be most on point.

Comment: You don't have any buttons. Do you mean the icons? To the right of what?

Comment: yes i mean  the icons

Comment: What's `<div class="controls"></div>` for?

Comment: for the icons that i  want to be displayed

Answer (score 1):

it's likely because your `div` for class `controls` isnt wraping anything, I assume you want the `</div>` after all of your control divs. like this:

```css
.controls {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 50%;
  right: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4tMg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="controls">
  <div class="control control-1 active-btn">
    <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="control control-2" data-id="about">
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="control control-3" data-id="portfolio">
    <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="control control-4" data-id="blogs">
    <i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="control control-5" data-id="contact">
    <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```